# Three.js running out of texture units

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have written an app using Three.js (r73) that allows the user to load multiple .dae files using the ColladaLoader.

If the user selects a sufficient number of objects the texture will not show for any of the objects...at this point I get this:

```
WebGLRenderer: trying to use 26 texture units while this GPU supports only 16
```

The error message seems fairly self-explanitory  - does this mean I can only load 16 textures at any one time? Is there a way around this? Can I render my scene with half my objects - clear the texture units - and then render the other half?

Quite new to Three.js - so sorry if its a stupid question.

Comment: Im curious, how did you manage to use 26 texture units?

Comment: I am using collada objects provided by someone else...I guess that's not going to work now I know that there is a limit on the number of textures within a single object.

Comment: @WacławJasper I am using collada objects provided by someone else...I guess that's not going to work now I know that there is a limit on the number of textures within a single object. Although I am still not convinced since this number continues to grow while I add multiple identical objects - so I'm still not clear.

Comment: The thing is tho, normally, a model uses no more than 4 textures: a diffuse texture, a normal texture, a specular texture and specular color or metalness texture. Perhaps you should speak to the provider why they need 26 different textures.

Answer (score 3):

This number is based on what your GPU supports, you can see it listed here at [WebGL Report](http://webglreport.com/), under `Max Texture Image Units: 16`.

Many people confuse this number with how many textures you can have in a single *scene*, this is false. This number represents how many textures you can use for a single *object* (i.e. in a single draw call).

So if you have an extremely complicated object, with hundreds of separate textures. You'll have to find a way to either merge the textures together, or split the object into multiple objects that can be drawn separately.

However, if you draw 1000 separate objects, each with a different texture, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Brendan...thanks - Good information. Not sure what you mean by a single draw call - is that the same as each object I add to the scene. I don't call a draw method for each object - I guess the renderer does this?

Comment: Each object within your scene should become a single draw call. The WebGLRenderer draws each object 1 after the other.

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes from exceeding the maximum number of "total" texture units, and *not* the Vertex texture units. Refer to WebGLRenderer.js, function getTextureUnit() for the reasoning behind this and the printing of this error message. (ex, https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/96702746/, line 4730)

To avoid the warning, analyse the shaders, and reduce the count of texture units required in the shader, for the rendering.

Comment: @prabindh...ok thanks. I need to do a bit more analysis on the objects I am loading - I am not creating them all myself. Do you know if there is a way of querying how many texture units are available at any time - maybe I could pin down the offending objects.